# Get a reference to the lambda's captured value

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, c++14

I am using a function (not mine, from a library I don't control) with a signature similar to this:

```
template<typename T, typename F>
void do_async(T const&, F); // the second parameter is a callable
```

and it usually used like this

```
do_async(obj, [this](){ ... });
```

I wrote a function similar to this that always uses the same callback lambda:

```
template<typename T>
void do_async_wrapper(T obj) {
    do_async(obj, [this](){ ... });
}
```

My problems stem from the fact that since the obj is passed as a reference, it has to be kept alive until the callback is called. My function is supposed to take care of that so the caller doesn't have to worry about object lifetime. That is why it accepts by value.
I would like to do something like this in order to keep it alive:

```
template<typename T>
void do_async_wrapper(T obj) {
    do_async(obj, [this, obj{std::move(obj)}](){ ... });
}
```

Obviously this wont (always) work as-is since the reference points to the function-local one which doesn't exist anymore, while the one kept alive is a (move-)copy of it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is `do_async` doing with that parameter? Are you sure it doesn't make a copy internally?

Comment: @TartanLlama Yes. The library docs specify that it is the caller's responsibility to make sure the object stays alive.

Comment: Can you link to the docs? One option would be a `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: @TartanLlama That would involve allocating another object on the heap, besides the lambda object (which I am starting to think is probably unavoidable)

Comment: @TartanLlama This is the actual `do_async` function: http://think-async.com/Asio/asio-1.11.0/doc/asio/reference/async_write/overload1.html

Comment: If the async launcher and async task both need access to the buffer, that sounds like a fairly good use-case for `std::shared_ptr`, even with the dynamic allocation.

Comment: @TartanLlama If you don't mind posting an answer showing a concrete example

Comment: Usually when this kind of thing happens, it is because a copy of the object being written to isn't the same as writing to the original referenced object.  Which is the parameter that must be kept alive?  The Stream, the Sequence or the WriteHandler?  The buffer sequence states that the "underlying buffer must be kept alive", but states the buffer can be copied.  So I assume we are talking about the stream?

Comment: @Yakk No, the buffer

Comment: @baruch "Although the buffers object may be copied as necessary, ownership of the underlying memory blocks is retained by the caller, which must guarantee that they remain valid until the handler is called. " That is a different set of requirements than you describe above.  The API does not keep references to the particular object, it copies it and expects the buffers referred to to persist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the functor is taken by value, you cannot store the object directly in the functor and pass a reference to it.
You may work-around that by using smart pointer as `shared_ptr`:

```
template<typename T>
void do_async_wrapper(T obj) {
    auto ptr = std::make_shared<T>(std::move(obj));
    do_async(*ptr, [this, ptr](){ /*...*/ });
}
```

Comment: I'd be tempted by `make_unique` instead of `make_shared`, as `do_async` shouldn't be *copying* the lambda.  But that requires an extra line to make it work (`auto& obj_ref = *ptr;`) in a defined way.

Comment: @Yakk I went with a similar solution using make_unique. I didn't need the line you show. What is the point of it?

Comment: @baruch: There are 2 problems, unspecified order between `*ptr` and the `[ptr = std::move(ptr)]`, and the copy of `F` in `do_async` (which make the 2 instance of `T` different).